# Почему double нельзя автоматически преобразовать в long?

Tags: java, информатика

я изучаю Java,меня заинтересовало то что, автоматическое расширение при преобразовании double в long не произойдет,хотя они занимают 64бита

Comment: А что такое автоматическое расширение при преобразовании вещественного типа в целое??

Answer (score 3):

Видимо ТС под автоматическим расширением имеется ввиду конструкцию типа:

```
int x=10;
double d=10.0;
long y=x; //автоматический каст
long z=(long )d;  //принудительный каст
```

Поясняю.

1. `long` занимает 64 бита, из которых 63 бита отводятся на значение, 1 бит (самый старший) на знак, в итоге `long` занимает от `-2^63` до `+2^63`
2. `double` тоже занимает 64 бита, но 52 бита отводятся на дробную часть, 11 бит на степень (мантиссу) и 1 бит на знак - [подробнее здесь](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), в итоге `double` занимает от `~-1.7^308` до `~+1.7^308`

Как видите внутренняя структура обоих типов совершенно другая и самое главное - максимальные значения тоже разные.

"Автоматический" каст проходит если только принимающий тип "шире" чем исходный, например:

```
long x=10;
double y=x; //работает потому что double "шире" long
```

а вот конструкция:

```
double x=10.0;
long y=x; //уже не работает, потому long "Уже" double
long z=(long )x; //нужен принудительный каст
```

Answer (score 2):

Потому что long это целое число, а double число с плавающей точкой. Если вы как разработчик знаете что у вас в double целое число, можете сделать явное приведение типов - но это ваше решение.